# Scala type miss match

Tags: scala, parsing

I am fairly new to scala and I am doing my assignment.
This is the code that I am using:

```
case EqNumC(l,r)  => (interp(l),interp(r)) match{
      case (NumV(s),NumV(x)) => if(s == x) BoolV(true) else BoolV(false)
      case _ => throw InterpException("Value not found!")
    }
```

When I run this code, it works fine and I get my result correctly. However this is somehow wrong. and I decided to make it better, by doing so:

```
case EqNumC(l,r)  => (interp(l),interp(r)) match{
      case (NumV(s),NumV(x)) => if(s==x) BoolV(true)
      case (NumV(_),NumV(_)) => BoolV(false)
      case _ => throw InterpException("Value not found!")
    }
```

However When I run this I get this error:

```
Status: CompilationFailure
solution.scala:129: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Value
      case (NumV(s),NumV(x)) => if(s==x) BoolV(true)
                                ^
```

I don't see the problem here, because it's almost the same as the other one. How can I get rid of this problem and what is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` control structure needs to come before the `=>` when pattern-matching. When it comes after, the compiler sees an `if` without an `else` and infers it to be `Unit` (no return type).

It should look like this:

```
case (NumV(s),NumV(x)) if(s == x) => BoolV(true)
```

The first version works because `if/else` returns a value, but a single `if` does not.

Comment: And even a bit neater:  `case(NumV(s), NumV(x)) => BoolV(s == x)` (although that's not what he was asking)

Comment: that fixed it for me. Can you say if you use if then else like I did in the fisrt part is the same as using two cases in the second? could you say they return the same value??

Comment: @David The two are logically equivalent. The first code sample will do it in one step, where-as in the second (corrected) sample, it moves on to the next `case` when `s != x`.